# Is it better to create one instance of a class or make an individual instance for every occurance?

Tags: java, performance, semantics

I've been hunting for tips on good Java coding practices, by looking at the code of accomplished programs. My first target was Minecraft, since I'd tried my hand at modding it, and I started to question my choice. Here was code from an accomplished game, and it was giving me two very different ways to go about things.

For those who don't know, Minecraft instantiates its items once and subsequently references that single instance and its methods for any operations it needs to carry out, using information from other sources for the method parameters. Its entities, on the other hand, are instantiated once for every individual entity in the world and are responsible for their own information.

So, the crux of the issue is: Which method is more efficient? Is there a particular reason to favor one over the other? Is it situational? Is it more efficient to do it one way or the other?

Comment: If semantic isn't the right tag, somebody let me know and I'll change it. Trying to refer to code style.

Comment: What is another "occurrence" of a class if not an instance?

Comment: Better in what sense?

Comment: I was going to write out a code example, but @Makoto pointed out a term for it - the singleton pattern.

Comment: @fastcodejava That's kind of what I was hoping for extrapolation on. There's always the idea of style v efficiency, and giving way for one when the other gets in the way (style usually being the latter).

Comment: I edited it such that it's not opinion-based. Style being a question of opinion, I omitted that part of the question. Purely speaking on efficiency now, and I believe Makoto answered it wonderfully, without an opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, in most cases, it depends.

What you describe is the [**singleton** pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), which there's one and only one instance of an object.  This is beneficial if having more than one instance is either expensive (such as multiple instances of a DAO), or doesn't make much sense (such as multiple instances of a DAO).

Individual instances of objects is necessary if you hold two separate, distinct instances of the same class - for instance, say you're holding two diamond pickaxes.  I wouldn't imagine that a singleton would make sense in that context, since you can interact with each pickaxe individually.

Use the pattern most suited for the situation.  There is (and won't ever be) any one-size-fits-all way of solving problems like this.